Spring system in two-dimensions based on graph network matrix representation
Wikipedia  page "Spring system" includes an illustration of modelling a mass-spring network, based on a matrix representation. The example uses an oriented incidence matrix, which derives from a graph representation of the spring system. The case of three nodes and two springs is defined with the following expressions:
$$
\Delta L = B^T X - L
$$
$$
F_{\rm{springs}} = -W \Delta L
$$
$$
F_{\rm{nodes}} = B F_{\rm{springs}} = -B W B^T X + B W L
$$
$$
\text{where} \quad 
X =\left[\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{matrix}\right]\text{,} \quad 
L = \left[\begin{matrix} L_1 \\ L_2 \end{matrix}\right] \;\text{and} \quad
W =  \left[\begin{matrix} w_1 & 0 \\ 0 & w_2 \end{matrix}\right]
$$
are the node displacements, the spring equilibrium lengths and the spring constants (assumed 1s in the example), respectively.
$$
B = \left[\begin{matrix} - 1 & \phantom{-}0 \\ \phantom{-}1 &-1 \\ \phantom{-}0 &\phantom{-}1\end{matrix}\right] \;
\text{is the oriented incidence matrix and $B^T$ its matrix transpose.}
$$
The method allows spring system dynamics simulations in 1D fairly straightforwardly.
Question: Would it be possible to extend the same approach, to a two-dimensional mass-spring network, considering that two-variable displacements would be required, and how can this be implemented with an oriented graph representation of the network?
